# Parsing & accessing JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I have JSON data (added a newline for readability) returned as

```
[{"pk": 7, "model": "pycourt_login.orders", "fields": {"status": 0, "delivered": false, "order_id": "6count1%2", "student_id": 5, "counterid": "counter1", "datetime": "2011-04-05 01:44:01", "dish": 6, "transaction_id": "2008010661301935441", "quantity": 2}},
{"pk": 8, "model": "pycourt_login.orders", "fields": {"status": 0, "delivered": false, "order_id": "9count1%1", "student_id": 5, "counterid": "counter1", "datetime": "2011-04-05 01:44:14", "dish": 9, "transaction_id": "2008010661301935454", "quantity": 1}}]
```

How do I access each item in jQuery.

I tried doing something like (assume that /pendingorders returns JSON)

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 
jQuery.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "/pendingorders",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(json) {
        $.each(json.results, function(i,dish){
            alert(dish.pk); 
            },'json')
        },  
    }); 
});
```

This is the error I get in Firebug:

```
object is undefined
[Break On This Error] length = object.length,
jquery.js (line 605)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current structure, I think you just want:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "/pendingorders",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(i,dish){
              alert(dish.pk); 
        });
    }); 
});
```

You had a stray `, 'json'` as the third parameter to `each`, and a comma after the success value (which is okay but probably unintended)

However, you may want to make the top level an object instead of an array, due to [JSON hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx).

If the structure were:

```
{"results":
[{"pk": 7, "model": "pycourt_login.orders", "fields": {"status": 0, "delivered": false, "order_id": "6count1%2", "student_id": 5, "counterid": "counter1", "datetime": "2011-04-05 01:44:01", "dish": 6, "transaction_id": "2008010661301935441", "quantity": 2}},
{"pk": 8, "model": "pycourt_login.orders", "fields": {"status": 0, "delivered": false, "order_id": "9count1%1", "student_id": 5, "counterid": "counter1", "datetime": "2011-04-05 01:44:14", "dish": 9, "transaction_id": "2008010661301935454", "quantity": 1}}]}
```

your original each line:

```
$.each(json.results, function(i,dish){
```

would be correct.

Comment: Thanks for informative answer. I thought ".results" was some method to make it iterable or something.

Comment: If we can do json hijacking, I wonder why I get that kind of result when I serialize result of a database query in django. They should do something about it.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing 'json' as a parameter to `each()` (watch the indentation). You can usually do that on `get()`, but `ajax()` works differently - setting the `dataType` option should suffice:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "/pendingorders",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        $.each(json.results, function(i,dish){
            alert(dish.pk); 
        });
    }
});
```

See the [ajax method documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for reference.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer.  I just wanted to add that if you configure your server-side `/pendingorders` code to respond with an `application/json` HTTP header, jQuery will automatically treat the response as JSON and deserialize it without a dataType specified.  Same end result, but a little easier.

Comment: I am returning json as mimetype='application/json' so I didnt need dataType. The real error was ".results" should not be there. I wrote it because I thought it was some method to make it iterable.